# Store return value to variable

Tags: powershell

I have the below code to convert assign **GB/TB** value based on size

```
$datastoreCapacity = $store.CapacityGB
$postfixes = @("GB", "TB", "PB" )
for ($i=0; $datastoreCapacity -ge 1024 -and $i -lt $postfixes.Length; $i++) { $datastoreCapacity = $datastoreCapacity / 1024; }
return "" + [System.Math]::Round($datastoreCapacity,2) + " " + $postfixes[$i];

$datastoreFree = $store.FreeSpaceGB
$postfixes = @("GB", "TB", "PB" )
for ($i=0; $datastoreFree -ge 1024 -and $i -lt $postfixes.Length; $i++) { $datastoreFree = $datastoreFree / 1024; }
return "" + [System.Math]::Round($datastoreFree,2) + " " + $postfixes[$i];
```

But when I am trying to assign the return value to variable like below i am getting error

```
$datastoreCapacity = return "" + [System.Math]::Round($datastoreCapacity,2) + " " +
```

Please let me know how can i store the value in variable

Comment: in PowerShell there's no need for the `return` cmdlet to be used like that. It may be simpler to use a formatted string like `$datastoreCapacity = "{0} {1}" -f [System.Math]::Round($datastoreFree,2), $postfixes[$i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make a small helper utility function for this:

```
function Format-Capacity ([double]$SizeInGB) {
    $units = 'GB', 'TB', 'PB'
    for ($i = 0; $SizeInGB -ge 1024 -and $i -lt $units.Count; $i++) {
        $SizeInGB /= 1024
    }
    '{0:N2} {1}' -f $SizeInGB, $units[$i]
}
```

Then getting the formatted sized is as easy as:

```
$datastoreCapacity = Format-Capacity $store.CapacityGB
$datastoreFree = Format-Capacity $store.FreeSpaceGB
```